# How to install R package directly from Google drive

Tags: r, installation, google-drive-api

I built a package for my company and want to put it on Google drive for easier access.

Now, instead of forcing the user to download the tar.gz file and then use sth. like `remotes::install_local`, I hoped that I could use directly sth. like install.packages with a respective Google link or sth. like `remotes::install_url`. But I don't get it working.

Any ideas how to install a package directly from G drive?

My current workaround is to use package `googledrive` in order to write a small script to download the tar.gz file, and then I'm using `remotes::install_local` by pointing to the downloaded file.

Comment: If the user has it mounted as `G:/`, why not just `install.packages("G:/path/to/package.tar.gz",repos=NULL)`? (Perhaps I'm assuming you have "mounted" the google drive to windows' `G:/`, did I misinterpret?)

Comment: Yesh, we don‘t mount the G drive, so it‘s an online-only access.

Comment: I don't imagine there's a package that does installation of packages from a googledrive share: since it doesn't appear to be advertised by the `remotes` package, and `googledrive` is not package-specific, I think your current method is likely the best you'll get.